# Show the value before a specific field based on date

Tags: r

Below is a subsetted dataset, I was wondering how do I go about for each set of ids, and sorted by earliest to latest date, create a new column that indicates the row before the "LTD" status? The purpose is to identify the diagnosis or row before hitting the "LTD" status for that unique id. Thanks in advance!

Dataset:

```
id <- c(123,123,123,123,123,321,321)
diag <- c("injury1", "injury2" , "cancer","injury4","cancer", "injury5", "cancer")
date <- as.Date(c('2008-11-1','2009-3-25','2010-3-14',"2010-10-14","2010-11-14", '2015-3-14', '2015-4-15'))
status <- (c("STD", "STD", "LTD", "STD","LTD","STD", "LTD"))

data <- data.frame(id, diag, date, status)
```

Result (N for no, Y for yes):

```
123 injury1 2008-11-01  STD   N
123 injury2 2009-03-25  STD   Y
123 cancer  2010-03-14  LTD   NA
123 injury4 2010-10-14  STD   Y
123 Cancer  2010-11-14  LTD   NA
321 injury5 2015-03-14  STD   Y
321 cancer  2015-04-15  LTD   NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the date to date object `arrange` by `date` , `group_by` `id` and use `case_when` based on conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(result = case_when(lead(status == "LTD") ~"Y", 
                            status == "LTD" ~ NA_character_, 
                            TRUE~ "N"))

#    id   diag    date     status result
#   <dbl> <fct>   <date>   <fct>  <chr> 
#1   123 injury1 2008-11-01 STD    N     
#2   123 injury2 2009-03-25 STD    Y     
#3   123 cancer  2010-03-14 LTD    NA    
#4   123 injury4 2010-10-14 STD    Y     
#5   123 cancer  2010-11-14 LTD    NA    
#6   321 injury5 2015-03-14 STD    Y     
#7   321 cancer  2015-04-15 LTD    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `by()` and step-by-step assignment.

```
do.call(rbind, by(data[order(data$date), ], data$id, function(x) {
  x$diag <- "N"
  x$diag[which(x$status == "LTD") - 1] <- "Y"
  x$diag[x$status == "LTD"] <- NA
  return(x[c(1, 3:4, 2)])
}))
#        id       date status diag
# 123.1 123 2008-11-01    STD    N
# 123.2 123 2009-03-25    STD    Y
# 123.3 123 2010-03-14    LTD <NA>
# 123.4 123 2010-10-14    STD    Y
# 123.5 123 2010-11-14    LTD <NA>
# 321.6 321 2015-03-14    STD    Y
# 321.7 321 2015-04-15    LTD <NA>
```